# Phase difference when sources are out of phase

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, harmonic-oscillator, interference

[image]
S1 and S2 are two point sources and the distance between them is $100.25 \lambda$ .S2 lags by $\pi/2$ then what will be phase difference between the waves at point on the line S1S2 left of S1.Actually this is a part of a question I couldn't solve correctly.
The phase difference due to path difference S1S2 will be $200.5\pi$ effectively $\pi/2$ ,since S2's phase is $-\pi/2$ compared  to S1 ,resultant phase difference between waves at S1 will be 0 ,implying both waves will be superimposed beyond S1 ,the answer then should be 0 (constructive interference as asked in the actual question) but my teacher and the book seems to differ ,they are doing some sorcery and claiming that actual phase difference is $\pi$ which leads to destructive interference and that is bugging me ,am I misunderstanding something ?

Comment: Can you provide the complete question so that we get more context?

Comment: The complete question is irrelevant in the context of my doubt however,if you say so ,the actual question required me to find the ratio of intensities at points left of S1 to points right of S2 ,therefore knowing the phase difference is important to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think about it this way: $S2$ is already "lagging" behind by the quarter of a period ($\pi/2$). In the geometry you are describing, it takes more time for $S2$ than $S1$ to arrive in $A$, resulting in additional delay with the effective path length difference $\lambda/4$ (or another $\pi/2$). So when arriving in $A$, $S2$, already lagging by $\pi/2$, will be lagging behing by $\pi$, resulting in destructive interferences.

I think your issue is you need to be more careful about the way you write your optical path difference. Here, $100.25 \lambda$ is the optical path "delay" of $S2$ with respect to $S1$. It means that $S2$ is delayed by $200.5 \pi$ with respect to $S1$ upon, arriving in $A$, corresponding to a relative phase of $-200.5 \pi$. When adding the already existing $- \pi /2$, you end up with a phase of $-201 \pi = \pi\, [2 \pi]$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you just subtracted instead of added, that's all. If $S_2$ is lagging in $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (quarter of a period), it means that after 100 periods, only $\frac{1}{4}\lambda$ away from $S_1$ there's an emitter which is lacking by a quarter. That means that until the wave will reach $S_1$, the emitted wave from $S_1$ will be ahead in another quarter, meaning a total of half, which is $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
EDIT:The wave is travelling leftwards and the points A and B are at $\frac{\lambda}{4}$ from center.I was missing this thing-the point (A) $\frac{\lambda}{4}$ from center ($\frac{\pi}{2}$ phase) will travel upward from the bottom point i.e its initial phase as compared to center should be $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ but I was under the impression that phase difference gained due to a path difference in the direction of travel is a positive value ,'gained' in sense ,this way the total difference is indeed $\pi$.
Why should the phase difference gained be negative in the direction of travel of the wave?
$$y=Asin(\omega t-kx)$$Let this be a wave,finding phase angles at $x$ and $x+\Delta x$ and subtracting ,phase difference is $-k\Delta x$ and not $k\Delta x$ as I was doing.